# Letter 'c' in math mode almost merges with the next symbol?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, typography, letters, amssymb

When typing the letter 'c' math mode I have the following problem, illustrated in the picture.

[image]

If we look on `ab` the spacing between the two letters seems normal, they seem like two separate letters as they should. But if we look at `cp` the letters seem almost merged. It might not seem like this on a large screen but on a small screen it is especially pronounced. Similar when I type `c\langle 0\rangle`, or `c\mathfrak{N}`. The last is `{c\, p}`
and in this case the spacing is too much, so this trivial solution does not work.

Is there any way to fix this? Of course not using letter 'c' in math mode is one solution, but is there any other more constructive way?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$ab, cp, c\langle 0\rangle, c\mathfrak{N}, c\,p$
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on the site please provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is to see if they see the same or if the problem is at your end.

Comment: Welcome! [This (click) is a picture at high resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9e5.png) and there's no clash. Don't trust screen viewers and, in doubt, look at the magnified output.

Comment: I agree with egreg, it looks normal. One may argue that it is a little close on the frak N but taht is the normal space between symbols compage with `c\mathbb{N}`.

Comment: @egreg totally agree. In fact I wrote about this in the question. It looks ok on a large screen, but looks merged even though 'ab' for example looks normal on the screen of the same size. But one can not expect everyone to look at it through a magnified glass. It should look normal even without magnified glass.

Comment: I suppose there is no solution other than not using letter 'c' in math mode at all?

Comment: @daleif in some cases evidently there should be more space between letter c and the next symbol.

Comment: I agree with you that at this size it looks uncomfortably close. When I compiled your minimal example and looked at it in my pdf viewer the space between the `c` and the bracket looked a little better, but the frakN was still way too close. In a different context but a similar situation (i.e. being annoyed by the proximity of two items) I used the solution of adding `\hspace{1pt}` between the elements. It's not very elegant, but it does a lot for my peace of mind. :p I use this also when writing regular italic text that smushes agains other characters, such as just before a parentheses close.

Comment: @Plergux thanks.